# Troubleshooting slow IIS and hanging ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, iis, windows-server-2008

Our ArcGIS Server 10.0 SP 4 website has been hanging lately where everything gets delivered except the map. When I try and check the REST Endpoints they it hangs and then fails. When I stop the IIS, that takes 2-3 minutes to stop, which is not normal. Sometimes it takes 2 or 3 stop/starts of IIS to get the server back working again. I've made sure ArcGISWebServices is in Admin group as well as all necessary server groups.

I looked in the system log for the latest crash and it reads:

> @ 8:18 AM "A worker process with process id of '13516' serving
>   application pool 'ArcGISApplicationsAppPool' has requested a recycle
>   because the worker process reached its allowed processing time limit.
>
> @8:30 (approx when I began investigating the issue) "A worker process
>   '7616' serving application pool 'ArcGISApplicationsAppPool' failed to
>   stop a listener channel for protocol 'http' in the allotted time.  The
>   data field contains the error number."

Any ideas on what I can do to further troubleshoot are appreciated.

Specs.
WinServer 2008 
IIS 7
AGS 10 SP4

Comment: Is this for all mapservices, or just one in particular?  Does it happen with a very simple mapservice?  See [related question on ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/questions/36683/iis-7-stopping-a-listener-channel), and [here on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863059/iis-web-application-hangs-periodically-needs-system-reboot).

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a common issue with ArcGIS Server 10 and IIS.

Please follow the steps in the following whitepaper from Esri.  These will configure the ArcGIS Web services and REST applications to run under a separate IIS application pool with the identity of the ArcGIS Web services user and disable per request impersonation.

[Configure ArcGIS Server REST API for the Microsoft .NET Framework to improve stability and performance](http://support.esri.com/es/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/36887)

This paper is for Windows Server 2003, but may aid other users that stumble across this Q&A.

[On Windows 2003 Server, the Local Security Authority Subsystem Service (lsass.exe) grows in CPU usage and memory utilization under heavy load](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/32620)